# Parsing Datetime string to Datetime in Xml Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, serialization

I am retrieving a datetime string as "2015-07-16T07:40:35Z".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people type="array">
   <person>
      <last-name>lastName</last-name>
      <first-name>firstName</first-name>
      <id type="integer">123</id>
      <last-changed-on type="date">2014-11-21T15:04:53Z</last-changed-on>
   </person>
</people>
```

I searched about this problem and found something like below.

```
[XmlIgnore]
public DateTime Start { get; set; }

[XmlElement("start")]
public string StartDateString
{
    get { return this.Start.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'"); }
    set { this.Start = DateTime.Parse(value); }
}
```

I want to deserialize that XmlElement to a Datetime property of an object. After that when I serialize that object I want to create a datetime string with format of "2015-07-16T07:40:35Z". So how would i change get/set block of properties for this issue.

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Why are you using ToString()? DateTime.Parse() will work : string input = "2014-11-21T15:04:53Z";
            DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(input);

Comment: I tried to datetime.parse but it didn't work. My last-changed-on element is now comes with type="date" attribute like <last-changed-on type="date">2014-11-21T15:04:53Z</last-changed-on> .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the formats you're dealing with are in the standard XML DateTime format. So in this case you don't need a proxy string property to handle it, you can use the built in functionality of the `XmlSerializer` and specify the `dateTime` data type on the relevant `XmlElement`. Update: specifying the `dateTime` doesn't work if the element is empty (even in combination with `isNullable`), here is a way to convert the string manually to a `DateTime`.

For example..

```
[XmlRoot("person")]
public class Person
{
    [XmlElement("last-name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("first-name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "last-changed-on")]
    public XmlDateTime LastChangedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: sounds like you have Xml where `LastChangedOn` can be empty or missing. In this case you can implement a custom class to handle the conversion and keep the `Person` class clean. I've added implict conversions so you can just treat the property as if it were a `DateTime`. Above changes slightly to have `XmlDateTime` instead of `DateTime`.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Value}")]
public class XmlDateTime : IXmlSerializable
{
    public DateTime Value { get; set; }
    public bool HasValue { get { return Value != DateTime.MinValue; } }
    private const string XML_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement();
            return;
        }

        string someDate = reader.ReadInnerXml();
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(someDate) == false)
        {
            Value = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(someDate, XML_DATE_FORMAT);
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        if (Value == DateTime.MinValue)
            return;

        writer.WriteRaw(XmlConvert.ToString(Value, XML_DATE_FORMAT));
    }

    public static implicit operator DateTime(XmlDateTime custom)
    {
        return custom.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator XmlDateTime(DateTime custom)
    {
        return new XmlDateTime() { Value = custom };
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed my attribute to this but I have an exception as "The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value". I think i should some datetime conversion as in my question but i can't find how to do it.

Comment: @Yusuf Duyar, Sounds like in your XML the date elements can be empty? See update, for a way to convert to a DateTime that handles this case. Personally, I don't like the idea of using the proxy string property, not very elegant.

Comment: thanks for your answer. as you guess another datetime field is can be empty and your solution fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of serialization you can use XML linq like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = 
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                "<people type=\"array\">" +
                   "<person>" +
                      "<last-name>lastName</last-name>" +
                      "<first-name>firstName</first-name>" +
                      "<id type=\"integer\">123</id>" +
                      "<last-changed-on>2014-11-21T15:04:53Z</last-changed-on>" +
                   "</person>" +
                "</people>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

            var results = doc.Descendants("person").Select(x => new {
                last_name = x.Element("last-name").Value,
                first_name = x.Element("first-name").Value,
                id = int.Parse(x.Element("id").Value),
                last_changed = DateTime.Parse(x.Element("last-changed-on").Value)
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: I wrote all my classes XmlSerialization based. So it's hard to change them to LINQ queries. But if I can't fix my datetime problem i will unfortunatelly change my method to this.

Answer (score 0):

If dont like `System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime(str, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")`
Can use standart function: `DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`